# Time-series data: How to code t-1 and t+1 based on value of specific variable in t0?

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, time-series

I am interested in learning how a specific factor such as foreign investments behaves 5 years before and after change, e.g. outbreak of civil war.

This is the *structure of my data* (the factor is not included here):

```
year country   change  time  
2001 A         0       ? (-1)
2002 A         1       0     
2003 A         0       ? (+1)
2004 A         0       ? (+2)    
2002 B         0       ? (-2)
2003 B         0       ? (-1)
2004 B         1       0
...
```

I am seeking to replace the question marks by the respective values in brackets, e.g., "-1" for the year prior to change (t-1) and "+1" for the year following change (t+1). The presence of change is coded with 1.

How would you do this? I am grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> dat <- read.table(text="year country   change  time  
+ 2001 A         0       ?(-1)
+ 2002 A         1       0     
+ 2003 A         0       ?(+1)
+ 2004 A         0       ?(+2)    
+ 2002 B         0       ?(-2)
+ 2003 B         0       ?(-1)
+ 2004 B         1       0
+ ", header=TRUE)
> with(dat, tapply(change, country, 
                              function(x) seq(length(x))-which(x==1) ) )
$A
[1] -1  0  1  2

$B
[1] -2 -1  0

> dat$time <-unlist( with(dat, tapply(change, country, 
                              function(x) seq(length(x))-which(x==1) ) ) )
> dat
  year country change time
1 2001       A      0   -1
2 2002       A      1    0
3 2003       A      0    1
4 2004       A      0    2
5 2002       B      0   -2
6 2003       B      0   -1
7 2004       B      1    0
>
```

Slightly less complex would be to use `ave` instead of `unlist(tapply(...))`

```
> dat$time <- with(dat, ave(change, country, FUN=function(x) seq(length(x))-which(x==1) ) )
> dat
  year country change time
1 2001       A      0   -1
2 2002       A      1    0
3 2003       A      0    1
4 2004       A      0    2
5 2002       B      0   -2
6 2003       B      0   -1
7 2004       B      1    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DWin! Again, your solution solves the problem efficiently and effectively. Many many thanks.